# Automatize Google Drive API connection with Mule 4

Tags: google-drive-api, mulesoft

I'm using Mule 4 and I want to do automatic application which gets data from google drive server when an HTTP request arrives.

I'm having trouble when I'm trying to connect to Google Drive API automatically when a requests arrives, is there some way to authenticate just 1 time to access to Google Drive API, and then, got a persistent OAuth 2.0 code which allows you to connect for life with it? Otherwise, any URL to get a code with no interaction once HTTP request arrives?

Comment: Which connector are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Mule Google Drive Connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/google-drive-connector/1.0/) to automate the operations.